# Implementing Nullable Types in Generic Interface

Tags: c#, exception, interface, reference, reference-type

So in a previous question I asked about implementing a generic interface with a public class and bingo, it works. However, one of the types I'm looking to pass in is one of the built in nullable types such as: int, Guid, String, etc.

Here's my Interface:

```
public interface IOurTemplate<T, U>
    where T : class
    where U : class
{
    IEnumerable<T> List();
    T Get(U id);
}
```

So when I implement this like so:

```
public class TestInterface : IOurTemplate<MyCustomClass, Int32>
{
    public IEnumerable<MyCustomClass> List()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public MyCustomClass Get(Int32 testID)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I receive the error message: *The type 'int' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'U' in the generic type or method 'TestApp.IOurTemplate'*

I've tried to infer the type Int32?, but same error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't really do this but it's probably the only way to get it to work.

```
public class MyWrapperClass<T> where T : struct 
{
    public Nullable<T> Item { get; set; }   
}

public class MyClass<T> where T : class 
{

}
```

Answer (score 7):

Nullable types don't satisfy `class` or `struct` constraints:

> #### C# Language Specification v3.0 (Section §10.1.5: Type parameter constraints):
>
> The reference type constraint specifies that a type argument used for the type parameter must be a reference type. All class types, interface types, delegate types, array types, and type parameters known to be a reference type (as defined below) satisfy this constraint.
>   The value type constraint specifies that a type argument used for the type parameter must be a non-nullable value type.
>
> All non-nullable struct types, enum types, and type parameters having the value type constraint satisfy this constraint. **Note that although classified as a value type, a nullable type (§4.1.10) does not satisfy the value type constraint.** A type parameter having the value type constraint cannot also have the constructor-constraint.

Comment: So what's your recommendation?

Comment: If you don't need constraints, remove them. If you want to use nullable types only, add a value type constraint (`where T:struct`) and use `T?` in the class definition.

Comment: What is the point of having such a rule? Surely Nullable<T> should satisfy the struct constraint, because it is a struct.

Comment: @buffjape Well, it is a special struct and does not satisfy the constraint. `Nullable<T>` is treated specially by the runtime: when a non-null `Nullable<T>` value is boxed, it is boxed as a `T` struct, not `Nullable<T>`. When a `null` nullable value is boxed, it simply returns a null reference.  The rationale is: imagine `int? a = null; if (a == null) {...} object o = a; if (o == null) {...}`, you probably want both `if` bodies to be consistently executed. In fact in early betas of .NET 2.0 which introduced nullable types, `Nullable<T>` was just a regular struct and `?` was just a syntactic...

Comment: ...sugar for manipulating `Nullable<T>` values. Due to this discrepancy, Microsoft decided to change the CLR to treat `Nullable<T>` specially. You cannot code your own `MyNullable<T>` struct and get the same runtime semantics.

Comment: So they implemented Nullable<T> as a pointer (not a struct or class), very efficient but then they needed to generate different code. The compiler already generates different code for class and struct type parameters. Why didn't Microsoft finish the job, and do the same for Nullable<T> (rather than exclude it from generics in what appears to be an arbitrary manner)?

Answer (score 1):

Any reason why you need to restrict type U to class?

```
public interface IOurTemplate<T, U>
    where T : class
{
    IEnumerable<T> List();
    T Get(U id);
}

public class TestInterface : IOurTemplate<MyCustomClass, Int32?>
{
    public IEnumerable<MyCustomClass> List()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public MyCustomClass Get(Int32? testID)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

FYI: `int?` is the C# shorthand for `Nullable<int>`.